# How to put a command's result into a variable?

Tags: linux, bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Storing output of command in shell variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4569/storing-output-of-command-in-shell-variable)

How can I put the result of `jps | awk '$2~/Bootstrap/{print $1}'` into a variable so that I can use with other commands?

Answer (score 2):

Wrap it in $( ... )

```
xyzzy=$(jps | awk '$2~/Bootstrap/{print $1}')
echo $xyzzy
```

this creates a subshell the output of which is captured into xyzzy.

Comment: "Nothing happens"

Comment: Note that *any trailing newlines are deleted.* .. This `$(...)` process is called [Command Substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution) and is one of the [Shell Expansions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions): ✦ brace expansion ✦ tilde expansion ✦ parameter and variable expansion ✦ command substitution ✦ arithmetic expansion ✦ word splitting ✦ filename expansion