# How to pipe output of find as input for diff?

Tags: bash, shell, diff

This is a basic question regarding bash but I could not find a solution.

I have many subdirectories with identically named files and I want to compare all of them for identity.

I can return list of this files with

```
find . -name "protein.mol2"
```

I know that file can be used as query in `diff`

```
diff -q --from-file dir1/file dir2/file dir3/file; echo $?
```

How do I pipe the output of `find` to `diff`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing output of command in shell variable](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4569/storing-output-of-command-in-shell-variable)

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev  I don't think this is a duplicate

Comment: @roaima Command substitution can be used in many scenarios, and I believe that `diff $(find)` is really the same as e.g. `mkdir $(date)`, or `var=$(pwd)`. Do you think those should be three separate questions?

Comment: @Dmitry definitely not! The potential complexity here is the correct handling of filenames containing spaces, etc., which doesn't lend itself cleanly to the `diff $(...)` style

Comment: @roaima That would be "why is my script failing on some files?" and I see no evidence of that in the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `--from-file` option allows you to compare one file against many files (rather than something like `tar --files-from` which reads a list of files to operate on from a file). It has an analogous `--to-file`, which of the two you use would depend on relative "direction" of the change. Since you're using `-q` which only says if there is a difference, this hopefully should not matter to you here.

I assume you have a reference file, and you wish to compare it to a set of identically named files, so either of these should work:

```
diff -q --from-file dir1/protein.mol2 $(find . -name protein.mol2)
find . -name protein.mol2 | xargs diff -q --from-file dir1/protein.mol2
```

In the first case `diff` will run only once, and its exit code will reflect whether or not any differences were found in the set.

In the second case `diff` may run more than once. This second form can be used in case you have a large number of files (or very long file/directory names) and hit a command argument limit (usually 128kB on Linux systems).

Answer (score 2):

try

```
diff -q --from-file $(find . -name "protein.mol2" -print) ; echo $?
```

- `$( )` construct  basically insert list of file from find.

Comment: Thanks, this works! But the second answer is more detailed.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to compare them for identity then you could consider using something like a checksum to tag the file based on its content:

```
find . -name 'protein.mol2' -exec cksum {} + | sort
```

You can save the output to a file. Lines with the first pair of numbers the same represent files that are (almost certainly) identical. This extension to the command will group files by identity:

```
find . -name 'protein.mol2' -exec cksum {} + |
sort |
while read c1 c2 file
do
    test "$c1-$c2" != "$o1-$o2" && echo
    echo "$file"
    o1="$c1" o2="$c2"
done
```

---

<sub>As a one-liner it's `find . -name 'protein.mol2' -exec cksum {} + | sort | while read c1 c2 file; do test "$c1-$c2" != "$o1-$o2" && echo; echo "$file"; o1="$c1" o2="$c2"; done` but it would probably be better off being put into a script file for reuse.</sub>